# MYSQL, is this kind of request possible?

Tags: mysql

I have persons (table **person**) who have 0 or N roles (tables **role** and **personne_role**). 
I want to select all the persons , with the roles they have, to have this kind of result :

```
PHIL COLLINS | Drummer | Singer

MIKE RUTHERFORD | Singer

ION ANDERSON | Singer

MIKE JAGGER |

CARLOS SANTANA | Guitarist
......
```

Each line can have 0 or N roles.

To do that, I make 2 requests

- the first one to get the employees (table **person**)
- the second one to loop all the retrieved employees and retrieve each role of them (tables **role** and **person_role**)

It works BUT in the case of there are a lot of lines, it is not very efficient.

I would like the same result in 1 request.

Is it possible ?
What are the mysql keywords I must use to do that ?

Thanks for your feedback.
dominique

Comment: JOIN and GROUP BY, GROUP_CONCAT are the keywords you want to be looking into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) with a [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), something like:

```
SELECT person.name, role.roles
FROM person
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT person_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT role SEPARATOR ' | ') roles
  FROM person_role
  GROUP BY person_id
) role ON (person.id = role.person_id)
```

EDIT: the fields name are just a guess, since you didn't show us the full table schema; also, if the roles are actually in a separate tale, say joined by a `role_id`, you'd need to add it to the subquery.

Comment: I did not know this GROUP_CONCAT instruction. It works fine. Merci !